# Standard z-index for expandale banners.

Tags: javascript, dom, ads, expandable

Is there a standard or de-facto standard for the z-index on expandable banner ads when they are in their expanded state? I am building an expandable banner and I will have no control over where it will be placed, so I need to know what I should set the z-index to set it to so that the banner above any normal page content but under any menus etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to *one billion trillion*.

There is no real **standard**.

---

The reason for this is because if you are arbitarily plaing the ad on a page where you have no idea the css of the current page, then you cannot possibly know what the max `z-index` is on the page in order to trump it.

Comment: Actually, I think that would overflow on some browsers.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to trump it because there is a requirement that any menus appear above the banner, even in the expanded state. It doesn't matter, I just gave the website owners the ability to set the z-index to what they feel is appropriate for their page.